# bash: syntax error near unexpected token `(' using awk and paste

Tags: bash, awk, paste

why do I get bash: syntax error near unexpected token `(' when using paste and awk as follows:

```
paste <(awk '{print$1}' file1.csv ) < (awk '{print$10"\t"$11}' file1.csv)
```

Thanks

Comment: Please, post some example data and expected output.

Comment: There is a space between "< (" while fetching column 10 and 11.
And we can achieve same result using awk - 

awk '{print $1,$10"\t"$11}' file1.csv

Answer (score 7):

You should not have a space around `<( )`. Command should be,

```
paste <(awk '{print$1}' file1.csv) <(awk '{print$10"\t"$11}' file1.csv)
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your environment, there's a chance that process substitution `<( )` isn't supported.

There are ways around this problem, as it's basically just syntactic sugar anyway.

That said, it look like you don't need it at all in your example:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{ print $1, $10, $11 }' file1.csv
```